# How can I exclude a specific folder from Google Drive search results?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

I want to search for let's say `*.doc` from all my files in Google Drive but I want to exclude results from a certain folder let's say `old docs`. What do I type in?

Comment: you can just remove the folder, search and re add the folder again

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly convenient, but it works.

1. Create a folder **X**
2. Move all other file/folders into **X**, minus excluded files/folders
3. Go into the **X** folder
4. Do your search
5. optionally move every back to original location.

Answer (score 0):

type "-foldername" this will exclude anything named foldername from the search results.

for more options check out [search options page](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You could rename the files that you don't want to show up in search with a unique string of characters of your choice and filter out those files. For example, if I only want complete documents and not "blank" documents, which for me are templates, I can use "-blank" (minus blank) to filter out documents with "blank" in their titles. I don't think there is a way to rename multiple files at a time in Google drive, but you could download the whole folder once to a computer and then bulk rename them, adding the string of characters you want to filter out. Then you could upload them again to Google drive and delete the originals so they don't show up in search.

Answer (score -2):

If you search .doc than click the recommendation and than it will search type:document and it will work! Tried it and it worked

Answer (score -3):

What I test, this search all text document in your Drive.

```
type:textdoc *.doc
```

It is what you need?

There is more operators which you can use in Drive (under plus with text "Advance search option").
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=en

EDIT (after Eight Days of Malaise reaction): 
Filtering by folder name is not possible in GDrive. Maybe use desktop synchronization app and after that use Explorer searching or some utility.

Comment: If there are matches in a folder like "flowers", they want to NOT see results from that folder

Comment: Oh, sorry. But filtering by folder name is not possible in GDrive.